# Open a file, read the lines, find a certain line and append a string to the end of it in ruby

Tags: ruby, append

So I want to read in my .bash_profile and append a string to the PATH.

Should I be opening the file and reading per line until I find what I want then replace? Or read in everything first?

```
File.open("/root/.bash_profile", "w+") do |file|
while line = line.gets
    if line =~ /^PATH/
        Not sure how to append
    end
end
```

Comment: Not even sure I'd use Ruby for this. But what have you got so far? For a relatively small file, why not read it all in?

Comment: Need to use ruby as it's part of a bigger script and moving towards chef here at work so want to work in ruby for all scripts. Either way, I have this right now, just erases the file. I will edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `w+` mode for files *erases all content* (I found this in a script that tried to modify its source). If you want to be able to write but keep content, use the `r+` mode instead.

NOTE: After seing your problem, why can you not append a line to this effect to the end of the bash profile?:

```
PATH=/some/path:$PATH
```

Or will this not work? Because the code for that is simple:

```
f=File.new("~/.bash_profile", "a+")
f.puts "PATH=/some/path:$PATH"
```

This may work just as well.

Comment: That would work except I need to keep other contents of the file intact including what is in the PATH already.

Comment: This would do just that. The `a+` mode is append mode, which unconditionally protects the current file contents. Because of the way in which the appended line is written, it will be prepending `/some/path` to the PATH, leaving the rest intact. Unless I missed something, this does exactly what you want.

Comment: Sorry after reading what you said it makes more sense now. Not sure I would use File.new though, would it not be a File.open with the a option?

Comment: `File.new` and `File.open` are (almost) the same. They are the same with regard to the filesystem (`File.open` has a handy block behavior). This will not override or delete any data in `.bash_profile`. The `a+` mode guarantees that.